# How can I clear the login information of GTA V?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

As with any other game game that requires you to log into an account, Grand Theft Auto V uses the Rockstar Games Social Club to authenticate and validate your PC game copy (even the Steam version).

How can I delete the saved login data of the RGSC? So during the next game launch the game asks for me to log in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache of GTA V login information is located on the following folder:

> [Documents Folder]\Rockstar Games\Social Club\Profiles

Over there, you are going to find a file and a bunch of folders.

To make the game request for your credentials during the next game launch, delete all of the folders and `autosignin.dat`.