# Does openening "Steam-Family-Shared" Rockstar-games link my Steam to the owner's Social Club account, or can I link my own, if I buy the game myself?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing, rockstar-games-social-club

So, before I got my own computer, I bought RDR2 on Steam on my brother's computer, so that I could play. Now I finally got my own and want to play, so we put on "Family Library Sharing". That way the game is now on my Steam account as well.

Whenever I try to open the game and log in with my own Rockstar (or is it called Social Club?) account (I used to play on my brother Rockstar account as well), it won't log me in. Obviously, this must be, because the game is his? And therefore his Rockstar account is linked?

So my question is, if I instead **buy the game** on my own, will I be able to play the game on my own Rockstar account? I could just try and buy GTAV or something, but I don't want to waste my money, if it doesn't work.

I know there's something about Rockstar accounts being linked to Steam accounts. So I want to know, if my Steam account is now linked to my brothers Rockstar, since I tried to open a game os his, or if there's still hope, that I can link my own account?

I'm sorry if this makes no sense. But please, if you have any knowledge on this, let me know. I've tried contacting Rockstar, but they can't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Family sharing does not install files on unique computers, and your computer has no way of knowing what you did using your brother's computer. Same with Rockstar Social Club. If you continued to use your brother's accounts on *your* computer but now want to switch, then you probably want to look into clearing the login cache on Rockstar Social Club.

See, for example:
[How can I clear the login information of GTA V?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356369/how-can-i-clear-the-login-information-of-gta-v)

Answer (score 0):

Games on Steam that are use the Rockstar Games Launcher work in a special way, where the Steam account is linked to a Rockstar Games account, and only said Social Club account is allowed to play the game. This makes the game unable to be shared via Family Sharing.

If you bought the game with your brother's account and your brother had his Steam account linked to his Rockstar Games account, only he will be able to play the game, and you will be unable to share it with your account.

If your Rockstar Games account is associated to your Brother's account, you will be unable to play any game, even if you buy it on your account, as the account's wouldn't match. The only solution is to contact Rockstar Support and try to get your Rockstar account unlinked from your brother's Steam account.